# How do I rotate an image clockwise using the Windows command line?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe

Is there a way to rotate images stored in folders clockwise so they can be changed from Landscape to Portrait using CMD or Powershell?

If there isn't a way to do it then please let me know. It might be best to use the PIL package in Python.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The Scripting Guys](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/07/05/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-convert-graphics-files-to-different-file-formats.aspx):

```
$path = "C:\Users\Me\Pictures\image.png"

[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms"); 
$i = new-object System.Drawing.Bitmap $path

$i.RotateFlip("Rotate90FlipNone")

$i.Save($path,"png")
```

That post from The Scripting Guys has a list of rotation types you can use with the `RotateFlip()` method.